# insert statement sql inserting values into a table in mysql with a where clause condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have rails application and its using mysql.

I have a piles table with two columns that I care for.

The columns are name_he_il and name_en_us

I don't have a problem doing these

```
select name_he_il from piles;
select name_en_us from piles;
```

I need to insert data into the name_he_il column into the piles table where name_en_us = "a specific value"

I tried something like this

```
insert into piles (name_he_il) values 'לא מאפיין כלל' where name_en_us = "Extremely Uncharacteristic";
```

I am getting syntax error.

I was googling and I figured the sql should be

insert into table (column 1) values (blah) where conditions;

but its not working.

Basically that hebrew text means extremely uncharacteristic.

Comment: That would be an UPDATE

Comment: You are mixing INSERT and SELECT. There is no WHERE clause in INSERT statement. Maybe you are trying to UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do UPDATE and not INSERT:

```
UPDATE piles SET name_he_il = 'לא מאפיין כלל' WHERE name_en_us = "Extremely Uncharacteristic";
```

Comment: I am taking this answer because it answered the question exactly including the sql statement plus I saw this one first.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `UPDATE ... WHERE`

INSERT is for creating new records only.

Answer (score 1):

Insert query is to insert new rom into table. If you already have row with value of "name_he_il" column then you need to use update.

```
UPDATE piles SET name_he_il='new value' WHERE name_he_es = 'something'
```